# Printing only lines with timestamps larger than a input timestamp?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, awk, grep

I am using `Python` to process outputs from hadoop filesystem which contain timestamp and a file name.

Since the output is long, I want to print only the lines that has not been checked.

For this, I am going to store a timestamp `last_ts`, which is the last time the system was checked.

To print the whole output, I am using the command

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/to/donemarkerfiles/ | sort -k 6 |awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8} '
```

where 6 is the day, 7 is the time, and 8 is the content.

I want to compare 6 and 7 with `last_ts`, and print only certain lines.

How can I do this? I tried to use `if` condition in `awk`, but I stumbled a lot and gave up.

---

Sample output :

```
2014-06-23 05:45 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140621_basic.done
2014-06-23 07:13 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140621_stat.done
2014-06-23 08:08 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140621_raw.done
2014-06-23 09:30 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140621_join.done
2014-06-23 09:31 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140621_upload_file.done
2014-06-23 15:52 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140622_basic.done
2014-06-23 20:23 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140622_stat.done
2014-06-23 21:40 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140622_raw.done
2014-06-23 22:57 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140622_join.done
2014-06-23 22:58 /user/hdfs/warehouse/donemarkers/20140622_upload_file.done
```

Comment: Where are you storing `last_ts`? What did you try for your `if` in awk?

Comment: Show some sample input and the value of `last_ts`

Comment: hadoop fs -ls /path/to/done | sort -k 6 |awk if ($6 > '2014-05-30 05:05') '{print $6" "$7" "$8} '

Comment: `last_ts = '2014-05-30 05:05'`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Show 5 random lines from the *output of the hadoop command*.

Comment: and please include it in your question. Don't make anyone reading this question read an ever-growing thread of comments. Use the `{}` tool at the top-left of the edit box after you copy/paste and highlight the block of sample data. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide sample output of `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/donemarkerfiles/` so that those of us without `hadoop` on our systems can help you.

Comment: I added the output from command `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/donemarkerfiles/ | sort -k 6 |awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8} '
` to the original post. Sorry for latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was ridiculously hard to figure out, I guess mainly because I'm not an awk expert. However, this does the heavy lifting:

`cat /tmp/data | awk '{"date -d \"" $1 " " $2 "\" +%s"|getline secs; print secs, $0}'`

Use awk to call the standard `date` util to format as epoch secs, and assign that return value to an awk variable with getline. In my command I just printed everything out, now let's do the filtering.

`cat /tmp/data | awk '{"date -d \"" last_ts "\" +%s"|getline mindate; "date -d \"" $1 " " $2 "\" +%s"|getline secs; if (secs > mindate) print $0}'`

Now we've got two things of the form `cmd|getline var` in there, which seems unwieldy. I would put that in a script (with a comment) but I'd never type it 'live'. Also, I'm not clear where `last_ts` lives. In the awk script already?